# Perform multiple reductions at the same time in pytorch/libtorch

Tags: pytorch

I have two tensor `values` and `indicator` that have the same shape. I wonder whether there is a build in function

```
max_values = function(values, indicator)
```

such that `max_values[i]` is the maximum of all values in `values` where `indicator == i`. I would also like to have similar functions for e.g. the sum/mean and minimum.

I tried googling the problem but without success since I lack the right keywords. I am still quite new to torch.